# Can't delete or hide duplicate Ubuntu Profile in Windows Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1737942/1210833), I see two WSL profiles, but I'm unable to delete or hide them as suggested in that answer:

[image: terminal showing two profiles]

`wslconfig /l` in PowerShell shows only one distro installed:

[image: power shell showing one instance installed]

I've tried setting the profile as Hidden, but it reappears after restarting Windows Terminal.  Even deleting the profile has the same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different profiles of the same WSL2 linux instance in Windows Terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/1737942/different-profiles-of-the-same-wsl2-linux-instance-in-windows-terminal). It's a combination of likely a bug in the detection of WSL installation within Windows Terminal, how that detection works, the profiles are in reality the same.  You can resolve this by manually editing the JSON file to remove the unwanted copy.

Comment: That greatly helps, but doesn't solve the problem. Left a comment there. Thanks for the direction @ramhound

Comment: You both have the same question.  The answer that question receive most definitely answers your question.

Comment: See the response to my comment there by the poster that posted the correct question. He doesn't understand why my profile appears even though it's marked inactive.

Comment: So here's the confusion (on the duplicate topic) - I agree with @Ramhound that the question *as it is currently written* is pretty much exactly the same as the other one.  However, in the comment on the other one you mentioned that (a) the profile didn't go away when you marked it hidden, and (b) the profile reappeared after deleting it and restarting Terminal.  I don't see that mentioned anywhere in this question.  If you edit this question to mention that, it should no longer be a duplicate.

Comment: Added a reference to that change, @NotTheDr01ds

Comment: @aagha Just noticed when pointing another user to this question that you never provided any feedback on my answer below.  Did it work for you?  Did you ultimately get it resolved in another way?  And if so, can you either accept my answer or post a new one with what did work for you?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

*Short-answer:*

Renaming your Windows Terminal `settings.json` *and* `state.json` should allow you to delete and/or hide the profiles once again.

Read on for explanation and other alternatives:

---

After some experimentation, I can reproduce at least parts of this.  As noted in my answer on the other question, the two profiles are:

- The auto-generated, generic profile that Windows Terminal creates for each WSL distribution (the one with the Linux Penguin icon).
- The JSON fragment extension that Canonical provides in the Ubuntu installation package that adds the Ubuntu color scheme and Ubuntu-specific icon.

You don't mention which one you aren't able to delete (perhaps it's both).  While I haven't been able to reproduce the "hiding" issue, it's probably related to the root problem causing the profile to reappear after deleting.

That root problem appears to me to likely be caused by the actual installation of two different "Ubuntu" packages.  While only one "distribution" can be installed at any point, there can be (and often, at the moment, are) two different AppX packages:

- The one installed by `wsl --install`.  This is currently still, it appears, 20.04.
- The one installed through the Microsoft Store.  This is now (as of the last week or so) 22.04.

Side-note: I'm honestly not sure which `wsl --install Ubuntu` results in, at the moment.  Since 22.04 recently became the mainstream (non-development) LTS release, we're in a bit of a transition period, which I think is causing the problem.

The resulting Windows Terminal profiles created when one of those is actually installed as a distribution will have different GUID's.  It's this GUID that Terminal uses to track deletion and hiding of the profile.  The profiles that have already been auto-generated (through either JSON fragment or the auto-generators) will be tracked in `state.json` that lives alongside your `settings.json` in:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState
```

So ultimately, through the WSL and Ubuntu re-installation on a test machine (for purposes not related to this question), I was able to get Windows Terminal into a similar "bad state" where I also couldn't delete the Canonical-generated Ubuntu profile (the Ubuntu icon).  The lack of the correct GUID in `state.json` meant that Terminal thought that it needed to be *regenerated* after deleting it and restarting.

The "easy" answer for recovering to a "good" state is to rename (or delete) *both* the `settings.json` and `state.json`.  When restarting, Windows Terminal will go through the auto-generation process again, but this time it will add each profile to `state.json`.

You can, of course, copy over any custom settings from the old (renamed) `settings.json.old` (or whatever you called it).

Alternatively, while I haven't tried it, you should be able to add the Ubuntu profile GUID that you find in `settings.json` to `state.json`.  It should look something like:

```json
{
    "dismissedMessages" : 
    [
        "setAsDefault"
    ],
    "generatedProfiles" : 
    [
        "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
        "{2c4de342-38b7-51cf-b940-2309a097f518}",
        "{b453ae62-4e3d-5e58-b989-0a998ec441b8}",
        "{51855cb2-8cce-5362-8f54-464b92b32386}"
    ]
}
```

Your `generatedProfiles`, of course, will probably look different.

With `state.json` fixed, you should be able to delete (and perhaps even hide) the profile and have it stay removed after restart.

At the moment, it appears to me that Windows Terminal not adding *newly* generated (or regenerated) profiles to `state.json` may be a bug (or just an oversight), but I'm not quite certain of that.