# WSL2 duplicated terminal

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL2 and everything went fine, but after installing, I see 2 different profiles in Terminal:

One has the Ubuntu Icon (left), and the other has the generic Terminal icon (right):

[image: Ubuntu and Terminal App]

They look different as well (Ubuntu *app* on the left; Ubuntu *profile* on the right):

[image: Left side Ubuntu App, right side Terminal app]

I then installed VSCode and called it with `code .`.  Then I noticed something:

- In the terminal with the Ubuntu icon it said it didn't understand the command.
- When I start Ubuntu from the Start Menu (left in the picture), it immediately downloaded and opened VSCode.

Now I don't understand why this happened. Aren't they the same terminals?

In [another post](https://superuser.com/a/1739388/1210833) here I read that in Windows Terminal the profile with the Penguin character can be hidden because it's a duplicate, and the one with the Ubuntu character is the right one.  But the profile with the Ubuntu icon is the one that isn't working for me.  However, when I start the Ubuntu *app*, that terminal works.

And the Windows Terminal profile that starts when I run the Ubuntu app is identical to the profile that starts with the penguin icon in Windows Terminal.

So which one should I use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use whatever you like.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14844/1210833)

Comment: Been pretty tied up today on other things, so it took a while to get a rewrite done on this.  Can you review it and make sure my understanding of your question is correct?

Comment: Also, please include the results of `wsl.exe -l -v` in an [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1756353/edit) to your question.  You might also check the results of `echo $WSL_DISTRO_NAME` in each of the profiles.  I don't think you are facing the "duplicate profile" issue I discussed in the other post, but perhaps something similar -- You likely do have at least two profiles.

Comment: "Aren't they the same terminals?" - No; Post your Windows Terminal profile json file.