# What're the differences between these 2 ways of of launching WSL?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, windows-terminal

I installed Ubuntu on WSL by doing `wsl --install Ubuntu`. When I went to set my profile in Windows Terminal, I see two different Ubuntu's.

[image: two separate ubuntu profiles]

The first one launches by doing `wsl -d Ubuntu` and the other just runs `ubuntu.exe`

The difference I noticed is that the first one uses my local filesystem whereas the one that runs `ubuntu.exe` uses a virtual filesystem. Which of these is the proper one to be using and how can I safely remove the other one?

Comment: You've done good research! However, I'd keep *both* shortcuts: use the one on local file system for *convenience*, e.g., sharing files, and the other for *security*, because it more effectively isolates Ubuntu from the physical drive and the OS.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik See my answer below (and/or the linked answers in it).  While you have a good idea based on what was presented in the *question*, the reality is that these two profiles are likely pointing to the same place, with just different *default* directories.  If that's the case, then both will have access to the exact same filesystems ultimately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The difference I noticed is that the first one uses my local filesystem whereas the one that runs `ubuntu.exe` uses a virtual filesystem. Which of these is the proper one to be using and how can I safely remove the other one?

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1737981/1210833) for some background on why you may have two different profiles pointing to the same WSL distribution, which one to remove, and how.  Also see [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1739388/1210833) if you have any trouble removing it.

As for the "difference" that you are seeing, it's likely just the *default starting directory* that is different between the two.

The one with the actual Ubuntu icon is created by the installer, and it should take you directly to your home directory in Ubuntu.  However, there may be some confusion here, because `~` (`/home/<user>`) is actually the virtual drive.

The one with the generic Penguin icon should be the one auto-created by Windows Terminal (which *should* have been removed/hidden by the installer-version, but sometimes isn't).  That one it will default to the *Windows* directory where it was executed from.  The confusion may be because this is going to appear as something like `/mnt/C/Windows/System32` (or another directory on `/mnt/c`).  That's actually your real, Windows drive, which is mounted into Ubuntu using a network share.